# Can a PAGEDLIST save the current URL? in ASP.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

**VIEW**

```
//Some Codes in my VIEW
@foreach (var item in Model._oList)
{
    //Grid table code
}

@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.activityList , page => Url.Action("Solution",new { page }),PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
//For my pagination Code
var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
var onePageNumberBugs = _oList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5);
ViewBag.activityList = onePageNumberBugs;
```

First load of my Page

```
(URL:) http://localhost:50969/Home/Solution?value=00003%20
```

When I click my Pagination from my page, the URL will  be

```
(URL:) http://localhost:50969/Home/Solution?page=2
```

My question is, How can I make my URL like this:

```
(URL:) http://localhost:50969/Home/Solution?value=00003%20&page=2
```

or

```
(URL:) http://localhost:50969/Home/Solution?page=2&value=00003%20
```

So that I can use my value for my controller for other purposes.

Comment: actions for my PAGINATION?? in my Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to pass the value as a MODEL

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.activityList , page => Url.Action("Solution",new { Model.variable_name ,page }),PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Resolution(int? page, SolutionModel _oSolutionModel)
{ /*Some codes*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

To retain your `value`, you should change your pagination link as follow:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.activityList , x => Url.Action("Solution",new {value = ViewBag.StoredValue, page = x}),PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

And your action will look like:

```
public ActionResult Solution(string value, int? page)
{
    ViewBag.StoredValue = value;
    //do what you want to do here
}
```

The trick here is to cache the `value` in your query string to `ViewBag` and use it inside your pagination link. So whenever you go to new page, you also pass your current `value` to your action

Comment: I have followed and copy your code but **Value = null**

Comment: Answer updated, change the `Url.Action` part. Please tell me if it work for you

Comment: the value is still *null*

Comment: did you navigate to this http://localhost:50969/Home/Solution?value=00003%20 URL before press paging link?

Answer (score 1):

try to send value in querystring from view

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.activityList , page => Url.Action("Resolution",new { page,value=YOURVALUE }),PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, p => Url.Action("", "Solution/" , new { p, tanz = Request.Params["value"] }))
```